# Layout questions with Style Elements and Elm

Tags: elm, elm-style-elements

I am building my first app in Elm and decided to use Style Elements package instead of CSS.

This is the layout that I am attempting. Its a single page app that does not scroll.

[image: Layout]

here is some code

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    layout Styles.stylesheet <|
        pageWrapper


pageWrapper : Element Styles variation Msg
column Page
    [ width (percent 100), height (percent 100) ]
    [ navMain
    , contentArea
    ]


navMain : Element Styles variation Msg
navMain =
    row Navigation
        [ spread, padding 10 ]
        [ el (Nav Logo) [ width (px 50)] (text "Logo")
        , row (Nav Link)
            [ padding 15, spacing 10]
            [ el (Nav Link) [] (text "About")
            , el (Nav Link) [] (text "Services")
            , el (Nav Link) [] (text "Team")
            , el (Nav Link) [] (text "Location")
            , el (Nav Link) [] (text "Contact")
            ]
    ]


contentArea : Element Styles variation Msg
contentArea =
    -- At this point I thought I would make a row with an el with the image 
       and a column containing the other two images. And other than creating heights with pixels I don't know how to extend the main content to the bottom of the page.
```

What are some good example apps I can look at to get a good idea of how to control the layout? I have looked through several, and I feel like I am just missing something very obvious because so far SE has been awesome to work with!

Comment: Your contentArea should be something like:

    `wrappedRow Style [] [ column Style [] [left content], wrappedRow 
    Style [] [ el Style [] (), el Style [] ()]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a very basic example:
https://ellie-app.com/k25rby75Da1/1

I've left the heights of the elements undefined below but you should be able to figure that out to suit your needs.  I updated the ellie link to a version that I think better approximates the height in your example.

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Html
import Html.Attributes
import Color
import Style
import Style.Font as Font
import Style.Color as Color
import Element exposing (..)
import Element.Attributes exposing (..)


main =
    Html.beginnerProgram
        { model = model
        , update = update
        , view = view
        }

type alias Model =
  { navbar : String
  , leftcontent : String
  , rightcontent : { top : String, bottom : String }
  }

model : Model
model =
  { navbar = "This is the navbar"
  , leftcontent = "This is the left column content"
  , rightcontent =
    { top = "This is the right top content"
    , bottom = "This is the right bottom content"
    }
   }



update model msg = 
     model

type MyStyles = Navbar | Left | RightTop | RightBottom | None

stylesheet =
    Style.styleSheet
        [ Style.style Navbar [ Color.background Color.red ]
        , Style.style Left [ Color.background Color.blue ]
        , Style.style RightTop [Color.background Color.purple ]
        , Style.style RightBottom [Color.background Color.gray ]
        ]

view model =
 Element.viewport stylesheet <|
   (column None [] [
   row Navbar [] [ text model.navbar ]
   , wrappedRow None []
   [ column Left [ width (percent 50)] [ text model.leftcontent ]
   , wrappedColumn None [ width (percent 50)] 
     [ el RightTop [ width fill] (text model.rightcontent.top)
     , el RightBottom [ width fill ] (text model.rightcontent.bottom)
     ]
   ]])
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me figure out how to think about it better and have now been able to make the layout about.